# Is thıs code efficient always for finding array[max]?

Tags: java

I am trying to find max value of an array, firstly i am shorting my array min to max after that i am using array[array.length-1] Is this logic efficient in large arrays?

```java
public static int findMax(int[] array){

    Arrays.sort(array);

    int max = array[array.length-1];

    return max;
}//end method
```

Comment: The best find max algorithm on an array is an iteration with O(n). To get any better you need to be using a more efficient data structure than a straight array, like a self balancing binary tree or any of a number of other data structures which maintain a form of ordering for you. or you can always memoize the max.

Comment: May not be efficient for the computer, but in terms of SLOC and maintainability it's pretty good compared to the suggested alternates....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No it's not.

```
Arrays.sort(array);
```

That line alone has an O(nlogn) running time. It can result in as many iterations as n, where n is the number of elements in the array, multiplied by log base 2 of n.

It would be much faster to just iterate through the array once.

```
public static int findMax(int[] array) {
    int indexOfMax = 0;
    for (i=1; i < array.length; i++) {
        if (array[i] > array[indexOfMax] {
            indexOfMax = i;
    }
    return indexOfMax
}
```

That has a maximum running time as O(n).

Comment: -1 For gross misrepresentation of big O. First off, when discussing sorting algorithms, n is (usually) the number of comparisons, not the number of iterations through the array. Also, O(n log n) does not mean "as many as n times log_2 n", it means "For some constants c, b: the number is less than c * n * log_b n (for all n > some constant N_0)". It might as well be 5 * n * log_9(n) for n > 1000.

Comment: @delnan: I would not call his claim of O(n log n) running time to be a 'gross misrepresentation of big O'. This is exactly the sort of stuff big O is used for, and he cited it properly.

Comment: Delnan is correct. However, my intention was to simplify things for the OP, who clearly has no CS education at all. And for an implementation of a library sort function, the base of the logarithm will invariably be 2.

Comment: @whatsisname He cited the right complexity but then interpreted it completely wrong. That doesn't help OP either, it just spreads misconceptions. I agree that my formulation is probably not useful for beginners. A more correct explanation that's *even simpler* is that it'll generally perform more work (than an O(n) algorithm) and is hence slower.

Comment: Delnan, honestly. Just edit the answer if you think you can improve it.

Answer (score 3):

Cleaner implementation of the accepted answer:

```
public static int findMax(int[] array) {

    // TODO: Take appropriate action if the array is empty.

    int max_value = Integer.MIN_VALUE;

    for ( int value : array ) {
        if ( value > max_value ) {
            max_value = value;
        }
    }

    return max_value;
}
```

Comment: yes, thats simple ans